# How to open multiple Mintty windows in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, cygwin, mintty

When I click Mintty's shortcut, it opens, if I click it again, it just returns focus to the window it had opened earlier. This is the shortcut's command I am using (I came to use it because it avoids a short wait before Mintty starts up as compared to `mintty.exe -`):

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe /bin/sh -lc 'exec bash'
```

How do I have the start shortcut for Mintty open another window instead of bringing focus to the old one?

I am using Windows 8.

Note: if I just enter the above command in Run or cmd it works fine – I can open multiple windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open another instance of an application, you have to `Shift+Click` instead of just clicking (or press `Shift+Enter` if you prefer the keyboard).
I've also found some very helpful additional information in [this question](https://superuser.com/a/643747/325141).